# JPA/hibernate - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. Can not insert null

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'am trying to implement manyToMany relationship. It works fine when getting data from database into entities but fails when trying to insert new value into join table.
I have three tables: job, job_prozedur and prozedur. Join table contains foreign keys to parent tables (job and prozedur) and few extra columns.

The entity classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOK_JOB")
Public class Job implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer id;
private String name;    

private List<JobProzedur> jobProzedurList = new ArrayList<JobProzedur>();

public Job() {}

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="seqJob", sequenceName="DOK_SEQ_1", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(generator="seqJob")
@Column(name = "JOB_ID")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}   

@Column(name = "JOB_NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "job", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@OrderBy(value = "sortLnr")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
public List<JobProzedur> getJobProzedurList() {
    return jobProzedurList;
}

public void setJobProzedurList(List<JobProzedur> jobProzedurList) {
    this.jobProzedurList = jobProzedurList;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Job other = (Job) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOK_JOB_PROZEDUR")
public class JobProzedur implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7971463524201735449L;

private JobProzedurId id = new JobProzedurId();
private Integer sortLnr;

private Job job;
private Prozedur proz;

public JobProzedur() {}

@EmbeddedId
public JobProzedurId getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(JobProzedurId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "SORT_LNR")
public Integer getSortLnr() {
    return sortLnr;
}

public void setSortLnr(Integer sortLnr) {
    this.sortLnr = sortLnr;
}   

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "JOB_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
public Job getJob() {
    return job;
}

public void setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PROZ_ID", referencedColumnName = "PROZ_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
public Prozedur getProz() {
    return proz;
}

public void setProz(Prozedur proz) {
    this.proz = proz;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    JobProzedur other = (JobProzedur) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

-

```
@Embeddable
public class JobProzedurId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

private Integer jobId;
private Integer prozId; 

public JobProzedurId() {}   

public JobProzedurId(Integer jobId, Integer prozId) {
    super();
    this.jobId = jobId;
    this.prozId = prozId;
}

@Column(name = "JOB_ID", nullable=false)
public Integer getJobId() {
    return jobId;
}

public void setJobId(Integer jobId) {
    this.jobId = jobId;
}

@Column(name = "PROZ_ID")
public Integer getProzId() {
    return prozId;
}

public void setProzId(Integer prozId) {
    this.prozId = prozId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((jobId == null) ? 0 : jobId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((prozId == null) ? 0 : prozId.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    JobProzedurId other = (JobProzedurId) obj;
    if (jobId == null) {
        if (other.jobId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!jobId.equals(other.jobId))
        return false;
    if (prozId == null) {
        if (other.prozId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!prozId.equals(other.prozId))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "JobProzedurId [jobId=" + jobId + ", prozId=" + prozId + "]";
}
```

}

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOK_PROZEDUR")
public class Prozedur implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer id;
private String dbName;
private String schemaName;
private String packageName;
private String name;

public Prozedur() {}

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="seqProz", sequenceName="DOK_SEQ_1", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(generator="seqProz")
@Column(name = "PROZ_ID")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "DB_NAME")
public String getDbName() {
    return dbName;
}

public void setDbName(String dbName) {
    this.dbName = dbName;
}

@Column(name = "SCHEMA_NAME")
public String getSchemaName() {
    return schemaName;
}

public void setSchemaName(String schemaName) {
    this.schemaName = schemaName;
}

@Column(name = "PACKAGE_NAME")
public String getPackageName() {
    return packageName;
}

public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
    this.packageName = packageName;
}

@Column(name = "PROZ_NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Prozedur other = (Prozedur) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

The part of code where I assign prozedur to job and persist is:

```
//      ...
//      ...
    JobProzedur jobProz = new JobProzedur();
    jobProz.setJob(job);
    jobProz.setProz(proz);

    job.getJobProzedurList().add(jobProz);

    entityManager.persist(job);
    entityManager.flush();
```

When persisting I get exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DOK"."DOK_JOB_PROZEDUR"."JOB_ID")
```

I don't know why hibernate doesn't assign values to foreign keys columns in join table during persist. Update works because I assign those values manually, but that is not the right way. Any help is appreciated. I've been working on this for few days now and I see no solution. Please help!

Comment: In your JobProzedur code, you configured both Job and Prozedur with "insertable=false, updatable=false". I guess that's why.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked the use of the composite-id for both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add an [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) annotation on `JobProzedur.getProz()` and `JobProzedut.getJob()`

EDIT: And as @PepperBob says: the associations shouldn't be marked as insertable=false and updatable=false, since you precisely want to insert them.

But I would make my life much easier, and the application faster, by using a single-column, auto-generated primary key instead of a composite primary key. Use a unique constraint to guarantee that two rows with the same job ID and the same prozedur ID can't exist.

Comment: Thanks! Your help is very appreciated. I was missing @MapsId. You solved my problem. Great :) I had some other issues but problem solved.

Comment: You should probably accept this answer -http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer